# get complete gradle project dependencies list

Tags: gradle, gradlew

how to get the list of all the jars and dependencies of a gradle project.

is their a gradle plugin compulsory to be used ?
if yes then which is the best plugin available for it.

and more important how can I exclude few jars which are being used by some of the dependencies in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a gradlew plugin - just use

```
./gradlew sub-project-name:dependencies
```

you may > operator for getting the output saved in a file